# NServiceBus on Mono

Tags: c#, mono, nservicebus, messaging, esb

With the move to NServiceBus 4, can we reliably run the ESB on Mono, yet?

According [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/particularsoftware/Cl6ggO2-T9I/3NCToqT1XkEJ) post on the official google group, we should be able to soon.

> OP: Will it now be possible to run everything on mono using rabbitmq as transport ?
>
> Andreas Öhlund: It's a first step towards mono yes. Our core still contains code using the System.Messaging namespace but as soon as we move that to a separate assembly there will be nothing stopping us from running on mono

As far as I can tell, rabbitmq is in a separate project, and the only place that references `system.messaging` is in NServiceBus.Core.Transports.MSMQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you should now be able to compile on Mono but we haven't tested this yet so it probably won't be as smooth as your regular .net experience.

Comment: @phillip I've checked and it still doesn't work out of the box. Our strategy going forwards will be to lean on the interoperability of the CoreCLR for running in other environments.

Comment: Thanks @UdiDahan.  Any idea on time frame?  Do you NSB 6 will support or is that contingent on the state of the CoreCLR project?  And for some context I'm interested in running NSB in Azure possibly using Docker containers for elastic scale out.  If I can get NSB to run on Linux my VM costs go down and Docker doesn't yet support Windows guests (AFAIK).

Comment: @PhilipPittle first and foremost, it would be predicated on CoreCLR, but then it would depend on how quickly the 3rd party libraries (Azure, RabbitMQ, etc) adapt to the CoreCLR as well. So no idea on time frame right now.